# Google sheets query select when certain values

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to make the formula bellow work as follows: Get the values on A when B matches the values on E (for the sample it would be 1,2,4,5,7,8).

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc";"DATA!A2:C")};"select Col1 Where Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'and Col2="&(E1:E2)&"";0)
```

sample data:

```
A   B   C           E
1   X   27/02/2019  X
2   Y   27/02/2019  Y
3   Z   27/02/2019  
4   X   27/02/2019  
5   Y   27/02/2019  
6   Z   27/02/2019  
7   X   27/02/2019  
8   Y   27/02/2019
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `QUERY` can't handle array/range inside quoted part
- `TODAY` needs to be with `()` like `TODAY()`
- today it's 28. february (at least where my sheet lives)

---

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc"; "DATA!A2:C");
 "select Col1 
  where Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
    and (Col2 = '"&E1&"'
     or  Col2 = '"&E2&"')"; 0)
```

[image]

or try like this if you have array/range of values:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc"; "DATA!A2:C100"); 
 COUNTIF(E1:E100; "="&
 IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc"; "DATA!B2:B100"))); 
 "select Col1 
   where Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
     and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 0)
```

Comment: Using array/range would be a better option. In case I have many values to filter, the query statement would be very long...

Comment: in that case you will need to first filter out and then query it. like: `=QUERY(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc"; "DATA!A2:C100"),
 COUNTIF(E1:E100, "="&IMPORTRANGE("1Cg9gx2IhBUYwElNXprNJnihixbMLJcK1DKzIClQDNwc"; "DATA!B2:B100"))),
 "select Col1 
  where Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 0)` note that it will be delayed so ignore that error for few minutes

Comment: I believe you would need brackets round this part of original answer 

Col2 = '"&E1&"'
     or Col2 = '"&E2&"'" because AND has higher priority rthan OR

Comment: Tom, you are correct. It is necessary to put round brackets. Tks

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try for the "where" clause:

```
where  Col2='"&E3&"' or Col2 ='"&E2&"'
```

[image: SO54912607 example]

Comment: It worked, although I would need to use it as a array/range. Thanks